# Magento - Add customer email into Address Templates HTML

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, email

I need to show the customer email on my order confirmations in the `Shipping Information` section. I know it is called in:

```
System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Address Templates
```

like so: (telephone number as example)

```
{{depend telephone}}Contact Number: {{var telephone}}
```

I have tried:

```
{{depend email}}Email Address: {{var email}}
```

and

```
Email Address: {{var order.getBillingAddress().getEmail()}}
```

but both come up empty. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to get this by adding:

```
{{var order.getCustomerEmail()}}
```

underneath:

```
{{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}
```

in the transactional email templates in admin

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work, because the address template is for the address, but the email belongs to the user.

It might work to `setEmail` on the address BEFORE it is formatted. The event `customer_address_format` should work for this.

Comment: No, unfortunately this doesn't work because the "email" doesn't belong to the "customer_address" eav entity type so it's not loaded in Mage_Customer_Helper_Address::getAttributes()

Comment: @ahe_borriglione You say that hooking into `customer_address_format` and adding the mail to the address object from the customer doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, because "email" exists already incl. value in address object because sales_flat_order_address and sales_flat_quote_address have an email column. But it is later (after event hook in) not overtaken in address format handler because "email" doesn't belong to address eav entity :/. So a rewrite would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have suggested a PR that fixes this for OpenMage LTS: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/1009